# Alternate java language

Tags: java, compiler-construction, syntax

Are there compilers around that use a syntax other then the java language syntax to produce JVM bytecode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modern alternatives to Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571267/modern-alternatives-to-java)

Answer (score 8):

Lots! scala, jruby, jython, Groovy, Clojure etc.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages

Comment: Clojure too. (And Grails is not a language).

Comment: I would also like to mention http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html which looks quite like Java but has some enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want to do but there are lots.  You can even port Java code to other platforms like android.

Depending on what you want to do with the byte code you might like to look at [Jasmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmin_%28software%29) which is a Byte Code assembly language and ASM which is a byte reader/minuplator/writer.

You can even compile [LOLCode](http://code.google.com/p/lolcode-java/) based on the language of LOLCats :D

```
HAI
CAN HAS STDIO?
PLZ OPEN FILE "LOLCATS.TXT"?
    AWSUM THX
        VISIBLE FILE
    O NOES
        INVISIBLE "ERROR!"
KTHXBYE
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty. Look at this [list of JVM languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of them ...

1. Lisp : [Lisp as an Alternative to Java](http://norvig.com/java-lisp.html)
2. Scala,
3. Jython,
4. JRuby,
5. Groovy etc ..

Have a look at the following link :

- [Modern Alternatives to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571267/modern-alternatives-to-java)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/25)?

Alternatively, there is JRuby, Groovy and lots more arriving all the time. Scala seems to be the one that gets the most press at the moment though.